# MongoDB updateOne query throws error "Expected 2 - 3 arguments but got 4" when I added a callback function as the fourth argument

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to do an upsert query to mongodb database and return the document that was inserted or the one that was found, but I get the error **Expected 2 - 3 arguments but got 4**

Here is my code:

`const result = await users.updateOne({address}, {$set: {address, referralCode}}, {upsert: true, new: true}, (err, doc) => {console.log(doc)})`

I am new to mongodb. How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: What versions of the database and drivers? What does typescript tell you the expected arguments are? As a guess I've seen that mongoose no longer accepts callbacks (need to use `await`) as of 7.0 I believe, so that might be what's happening here

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't post images of the code in the question, paste the code itself. Secondly, you are using MongoDB node driver, which doesn't accept a callback. So your query should be:

```
const result = await users.updateOne({address}, {$set: {address, referralCode}}, {upsert: true, new: true});
```

This is the link to the official [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.1/classes/Collection.html#updateOne).